# Update Itinerary OpenReservationElement

Tags: sabre

```
<stl19:UpdateReservationRS xmlns:stl19="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19"
            xmlns:ns6="http://services.sabre.com/res/orr/v0"
            xmlns:or114="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14"
            xmlns:raw="http://tds.sabre.com/itinerary"
            xmlns:ns4="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrconn/ReaccSearch">
            <stl19:Success>FALSE</stl19:Success>
            <stl19:Errors>
                <stl19:Error>
                    <stl19:Code>700432</stl19:Code>
                    <stl19:Message>Reservation Orchestration Error Caused by:
                        [OpenReservationElement with pdsId = 122 not found.] Failure UUID:
                        [0e39b500-8e39-430b-8b81-c1e3d5afa528]</stl19:Message>
                    <stl19:Severity>MODERATE</stl19:Severity>
                </stl19:Error>
            </stl19:Errors>
        </stl19:UpdateReservationRS>
```

I'm trying to update the date of birth on the passport which is under OpenReservationElement

I'm not sure why id is not found. Can confirm that it exists based on Get Reservation API response. Happy to post it here but it's quite long.

Here's my request:

```
<UpdateReservationRQ Version="1.19.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19">
            <RequestType>Stateless</RequestType>
            <ReturnOptions IncludeUpdateDetails="true" ReturnLocator="true" />
            <ReservationUpdateList>
                <Locator>HUJBWT</Locator>
                <ReservationUpdateItem>
                    <OpenReservationElementUpdate id="122" op="U">
                        <OpenReservationElement>
                            <ServiceRequest xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14">
                                <TravelDocument>
                                    <DateOfBirth>11-01-1985</DateOfBirth>
                                </TravelDocument>
                            </ServiceRequest>
                        </OpenReservationElement>
                    </OpenReservationElementUpdate>
                </ReservationUpdateItem>
                <ReceivedFrom>
                    <AgentName>CedricHije</AgentName>
                </ReceivedFrom>
            </ReservationUpdateList>
        </UpdateReservationRQ>
```